# Linux logger doesn't write tags to log files?

Tags: linux, logging, syslog-ng

I have a problem with logger command. After upgrading syslog-ng to 3.3th version (maybe it is not directly depend on it), logger (using command below) doesn't log tag names:

```
logger -t "BLABLA"  some_log_string
```

How can I solve it? I searched around but couldn't find anything regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange - you cannot switch to rsyslog? Using 5.8.11 and works as expected...

Comment: You need to provide more information. Relevant parts of your configuration file, package version, distribution. What you did and what did you expect to happen, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this problem myself. Apperantly, the creators of syslog-ng have changed it a bit in the new version (3.0), which I use syslog-ng 3.3. In order to display the log messages with application name, we have to include `$MSGHDR` directive with `$MSG`. Example template will be like:

```
template("$DATE $YEAR $MSGHDR$MSG\n")
```

From now on, the syslog-ng will log like this:

Dec 15 15:22:01 2012 fw_update_app: fw dir found